Some trouble with PSQLException and @JsonProperty annotation
I spent three hours figuring out the reason for the PSQLException, why the data came from Postman, namely the contactData field as null, it turned out that annotation suggested me the bot @JsonProperty("contact_data"), and in the questions to him I could not find the reason). But I still did not understand why the converter did not work when specifying this annotation?
What idea sugessted: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "contact_data" is of type jsonb, and expression is character varying
Hint: Rewrite the expression or convert its type."
@Column(name = "contact_data", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Converter
public class MapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> attribute) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(attribute);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new MapConversionException("Failed to convert Map to String", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, Map.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MapConversionException("Failed to convert Map to String", e);
        }
    }
}



